# Dynamically add and remove button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

The essence of my program is the user can click for an amount of textboxes and radiobuttons they want to add by clicking on a button and using a numericUpDown. After clicking the button the program adds a button under the text boxes, but if I change the number of rows the first button stays and a new one gets created. So I would like to know how can I only have the one button? Would it also be possible for me to apply this with removing the textboxes and radiobuttons.

This is my code for the button handler

```
 int length = (int)this.numericUpDownNumComp.Value;
        bool created = false;
        CustomButton c = new CustomButton();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            //instantiate and configure the text boxes
            textboxComputer.Add(new TextBox());
            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point(176, 114 + i * 25);
            //to evoke an object in an ArrayList we use the 'as' keyword
            (textboxComputer[i] as TextBox).Location = p;
            (textboxComputer[i] as TextBox).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 20);
            //use 'as' again here to add the control to the controls Collection
            this.Controls.Add(textboxComputer[i] as TextBox);
            //instantiate and configure the labels
            this.labels.Add(new Label());
            System.Drawing.Point pLabel = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 114 + i * 25);
            (labels[i] as Label).Location = pLabel;
            (labels[i] as Label).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 13);

            (labels[i] as Label).Text = @"Computer " + (i + 1).ToString() + ":";
            this.Controls.Add((labels[i] as Label));
            //add some mouse events
            (textboxComputer[i] as TextBox).MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_mouseEnter);
            (textboxComputer[i] as TextBox).MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_mouseLeave);
            //add the radio buttons - these are already sized  (See RadioButtons.cs) so just need to place at a point
            radioButtons.Add(new RadioButtons());
            (radioButtons[i] as RadioButtons).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(370, 110 + i * 25);
            this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i] as RadioButtons);
            int last = length - 1;


        }
        if (created == true)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(c as Button);
            //(c as Button).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(370, 110 + i * 25 + 25);
            created = false;
        }

            created = true;
            this.Controls.Add(c as Button);
            (c as Button).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(370, 110 + length * 25 + 25);
```

Comment: having hard time reading it right now... instead of abusing the `as textbox` you should just set all of its properties on a temp texbox var before you add it to the list

Comment: I don't know the whole concept but wouldn't it be easier to use e.g. GridView for adding rows etc.?

Comment: This is an exercise I am trying to workout, if possible could you please tell me what you don't understand and I will try to explain

Comment: I may be totally wrong about this but it seems as if the boolean never gets set to true so it never removes the button. Am I reading that right?

Comment: @StevenMarciano Yes it appears as though you are I just checked with a console line and it didn't go to the condition

Comment: Don't worry, I do that all the time with booleans